# Index row as column header

Tags: r

How can I change a data frame so that the row index is used as column header?

I have this data:

```
0   1.052
1   0.542
2   0.496
3   0.402
4   0.278
0   5.115
1   4.329
2   4.121
3   4.075
4   4.0088
...
```

I would like to get it so that I get a matrix with the index as column header and the second column under its index?

Comment: i just used the first solution I got becouse it worked for what im trying to do, I dont mind the error messages, Im realy bad with R so i try to avoid doing to complicated things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the matrix function and change the default value of `byrow`:

```
## Create some example data
dd = data.frame(x = 0:4, y=runif(5*5))

## Specify the number of columns
## Order by Row   
matrix(dd[,2], ncol=length(unique(dd[,1])), byrow = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible `data.table` solution (you didn't provide column names so I assumed it's `V1` and `V2`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, indx := cumsum(V1 == 0)]
dcast(df, indx ~ V1, value.var = "V2")
#    indx     0     1     2     3      4
# 1:    1 1.052 0.542 0.496 0.402 0.2780
# 2:    2 5.115 4.329 4.121 4.075 4.0088
```

Or even simpler (proposed by @akrun)

```
library(reshape2) 
acast(df, cumsum(V1 == 0) ~ V1, value.var = 'V2')
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), 
      V2 = c(1.052, 0.542, 0.496, 0.402, 0.278, 5.115, 4.329, 4.121, 
      4.075, 4.0088)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
     -10L))
```

Comment: Basically, I want to say `library(reshape2);
acast(df, cumsum(V1==0)~V1, value.var='V2')` if the OP wanted a matrix output

Comment: @akrun OP said they have a data frame, but accepted a matrix solution, so I'm not sure what they have there really

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get your point, but it seems like you are willing to treat a column as header, or key. In this context I would simply suggest to use the `data.table` package and especially the `setkey` function

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unstack`:

```
unstack(dat, y ~ x)
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame, `x` is the name of the first (indicator) column, and `y` is the name of the second (value) column.

An example:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(x = 0:4, y = rnorm(10))
#    x          y
# 1  0 -0.6264538
# 2  1  0.1836433
# 3  2 -0.8356286
# 4  3  1.5952808
# 5  4  0.3295078
# 6  0 -0.8204684
# 7  1  0.4874291
# 8  2  0.7383247
# 9  3  0.5757814
# 10 4 -0.3053884

unstack(dat, y ~ x)
#           X0        X1         X2        X3         X4
# 1 -0.6264538 0.1836433 -0.8356286 1.5952808  0.3295078
# 2 -0.8204684 0.4874291  0.7383247 0.5757814 -0.3053884
```